# How to use a super-trait as parameter?

Tags: rust, traits

I have some elements with a 2D position. Since most of them are (almost) round, to simplify I use the distance to check if two of them have collided.

While I **can** call a method from a "parent" trait, I **cannot** use it as a parameter where a parent trait is required.

```
trait Point {
    fn x(&self) -> f64;
    fn y(&self) -> f64;
    fn distance(&self, other: &Point) -> f64 {
        ((other.x() - self.x()).powi(2) + (other.y() - self.y()).powi(2)).sqrt()
    }
}

trait Round: Point {
    fn radius(&self) -> f64;

    fn collision(&self, other: &Round) -> bool {
        let distance: f64 = self.distance(other);
        distance < self.radius() + other.radius()
    }
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:13:43
   |
13 |         let distance: f64 = self.distance(other);
   |                                           ^^^^^ expected trait `Point`, found trait `Round`
   |
   = note: expected type `&Point`
              found type `&Round`
```

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks to point me to the correct answer ... @Shepmaster. I have search for a while but did not use the correct terms ...

Comment: No worries; that's why Stack Overflow has duplicates. This question will remain as a signpost for everyone else who searches using the same terms you did.